# The range of an inverse function

Tags: functions

I study maths as a hobby. I have the following question:

Find the inverse function of $f(x) = \frac{1}{(px + q)}$, $x \ne \frac{-q}{p}$ where *p* and *q* are positive constants.

Now, I can find the inverse function easily enough. The book gives the answer as:

$f^{-1} = \frac{1 - qx}{px} (x \ne 0)$

It is this last part I cannot figure out. Why $(x \ne 0)$?

Comment: Division by $0$ is rarely a good thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to look at it: one is that given a (bijective) function $f\colon X\to Y$ we define the inverse to be a function $f^{-1}\colon Y \to X$. But your $f$ is a function of the form $1/k$ and this fraction is never zero, hence $0\notin Y$.

The second way is simply to note that setting $x=0$ would cause $f^{-1}$ to become undefined (due to division by zero), which would make the inverse invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $0$ is not in the range of $f$ (even though the range and domain is not explicitly defined.), thus it is not in the domain of the inverse of the function $f$.